# How to create a watcher to look logs of logstasher ? If there is an error, I want to trigger code to create a mail to developers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I am using logstasher 0.9.0, rails 4.1.2. I could not find any callbacks or hooks available in the gem. I need to watch the log file logs/logstasher.log. If there are entries containing errors, I want to create an email to developers.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is send the dev team an email when an exception occurs, you can subscribe to ActiveSupport notifications in an initializer:

```
    # Works in Rails 4.2.3
    # config/initializers/notify_dev_team_of_exceptions.rb
    ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe 'process_action.action_controller' do |name, start, finish, id, payload|
      begin

        # Checkout the payload param for info on
        if payload[:exception].present? # indicates an exception occurred in the request
            # Your code to send an email to the dev team ...
        end

        # You can do other things here, like notify yourself if a user tries an experimental feature etc

      rescue StandardError => ex
        m = "#{Time.now} Error occurred while instrumenting logging to the DB: #{ex.inspect}"
        Rails.logger.error(m)
      end
    end
```

Also, if you add this monkey patch to the top of that initializer, the payload can include the exception stack trace:

```
    # Monkey patch so the exception object is included in the payload, so that the backtrace is available.
    # activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb
    module ActiveSupport
      module Notifications
        class Instrumenter
          def instrument(name, payload={})
            start name, payload
            begin
              yield payload
            rescue Exception => e
              payload[:exception] = [e.class.name, e.message]
              payload[:exception_object] = e # <- Monkey patch. How Rails 5.1 does it.
              raise e
            ensure
              finish name, payload
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

If you want to add more info (such as request headers) to the payload, add this monkey patch to the top of the initializer as well:

```
    # Monkey patch so current user & more is included in the payload.
    # actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb
    module ActionController
      module Instrumentation
        def process_action(*args)
          raw_payload = {

            # START monkey patch
            :user_name  => (request.headers['some_header_with_the_username']),
            :ip         => request.remote_ip,
            :flash      => (request.session['flash'].to_s rescue nil),
            :req_uuid   => request.uuid,
            # END monkey patch

            :controller => self.class.name,
            :action     => self.action_name,
            :params     => request.filtered_parameters,
            :format     => request.format.try(:ref),
            :method     => request.request_method,
            :path       => (request.fullpath rescue "unknown")

          }
          ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("start_processing.action_controller", raw_payload.dup)

          ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrument("process_action.action_controller", raw_payload) do |payload|
            begin
              result = super
              payload[:status] = response.status
              result
            ensure
              append_info_to_payload(payload)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```